# VBA text to columns with "" delimiters

Tags: vba, excel

I will be quick.

I have a variable 'strLine' with text:

The exact string will look like that:

`"Text1","Text2","Text3","Text4","Text5"`

So, delimiter in my case is: "

How I can extract text and write it in columns.

Expecting results in cells:

```
A1=Text1
B1=Text2
C1=Text3
D1=Text4
E1=Text5
```

Thanks

Comment: You're delimiter is `,` not `"`. Then after splitting on `,` you need to trim off the `"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Split` function, it'll return a 0-based array (ergo +1 in cells) :

```
Sub test_Andy()

Dim StrLine As String
Dim Str() As String

StrLine = Range("A2").Value 'If your value is in A2
'If you input the value manually, not really practical with so much "
StrLine = Chr(34) & "Text1" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "Text2" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "Text3" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "Text4" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "Text5" & Chr(34)
Debug.Print StrLine '"Text1","Text2","Text3","Text4","Text5"

Str = Split(StrLine, ",")

Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(Str) To UBound(Str)
    Cells(1, i + 1) = Str(i)
    Cells(2, i + 1) = Replace(Str(i), Chr(34), vbNullString)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to use `Mid` instead of `Replace` in case the `Str(i)` contains quotes in it

Comment: Fantastic, Thanks @R3uk

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Split` to split the text into an array, then remove the `"` from the start and the end of the parts using `Mid` :

```
strText = """Text1"",""Text2"",""Text3"",""Text4"",""Text5"""
aSplit = Split(strText, ",")
For Each strCurrent in aSplit
    MsgBox Mid(strCurrent, 2, Len(strCurrent) - 2)
Next
```

Remark : You might want to add some checks to ensure that there is a `"` at the start and end before removing them.

Answer (score 1):

**edited** to simulate a `StrLine` loop:

```
Dim iRow As Long
irow = 1

For Each StrLine In StrLines '<--' assuming a loop through many StrLines
    Str = Split(Replace(StrLine, """", ""), ",")
    Cells(iRow, 1).Resize(, UBound(Str) - LBound(Str)).Value = Str
    iRow = iRow + 1
Next
```

Comment: Some explanation would raise the answer quality by a lot. It is flagged as Low Quality Post right now.

Comment: How do I use to switch 'A1' to next line for next string in for loop?

Comment: I get strLine from a file. Each strLine should go to next line in excel

Comment: see edited code. if it solved your question you may want to mark answer as accepted. thank you

Comment: @Andy, did you get through it?

Comment: Cheers. @user3598756

Comment: thanks for the cheers, but ... did you get through it with my solution?